# Shopping cart does not echo empty PHP

Tags: php

My cart is never echoed empty, even though the value is 0.
What am I missing? Please point me in the right direction. 
I've tried to move the else-statement but that only renders page errors.

```
<?php
session_start();

include "cart.php";
include "style.php";


if (isset($_GET['add'])) {
    $_SESSION['id'.$_GET['add']]++;
}

if (isset($_GET['empty'])) {
    $_SESSION['id_'.$_GET['empty']]--;
    session_unset();
}

function cart() {
    echo "<h3>Shopping cart!</h3>";
    echo "<table>
    <tr>
    <td>Product</td>
    <td>Quantity</td>
    <td>Price</td>
    <td><a href='shoppingcart.php?empty=$name'>[Empty]</a></td>
    </tr>"; 
    foreach($_SESSION as $name => $value) {
    if ($value > 0) {
    echo "<table><tr><td>$name</td><td>$value</td></tr></table>";

}
    else {
    echo "Cart is empty";
}
}       
} 

?>
```

Comment: Do you want to clear all session variables or destroy the session? There's a difference between the two.

Comment: This is a horrible design for a cart. How about `$_SESSION['cart'] = array();` Then build an array and put it in there. And retrieve the array when retrieving the cart. You DO NOT want users determining the names of session variables (i.e. `$_SESSION['id'.$_GET['add']]`)...that could be a security vulnerability.

Comment: horrible code design :/

Comment: Thanks for the input, I'm really new to this, and I appreciate the input. Would love to learn why my "else" statement isn't working though, as that is my main problem atm. @developerwjk

Comment: No, your main problem is that this is totally wrong. A session is not a cart and a cart is not a session. You don't put different items of a cart in different session attributes. And you don't unset the whole session to clear a cart. You need to start over from scratch doing it right.

Comment: I posted an answer showing a much better way to do it.

Answer (score 0):

A session is not a cart and a cart is not a session. A cart should essentially be one session attribute that contains an array.

Here is the basic idea (starting with your code):

```
<?php
session_start();

//create default empty cart
$cart = array();

if(isset($_SESSION['cart']))
{
   //get the cart from the session
   $cart = $_SESSION['cart'];
}

if (isset($_GET['add'])) 
{
   $cart[] = $_GET['add']; //add to cart array
}

if (isset($_GET['empty'])) 
{
    $cart = array(); //set cart array to empty array
}

//put the cart in the session
$_SESSION['cart'] = $cart;

function cart() 
{
?>
    <h3>Shopping cart!</h3>
    <table>
    <tr>
    <td>Product</td>
    <td>Quantity</td>
    <td>Price</td>
    <td><a href='shoppingcart.php?empty=true'>[Empty]</a></td>
    </tr>
<?php
    if(empty($cart))
    {
       echo "Cart is empty";
    }
    else
    {
       echo "<table>";
       foreach($cart as $name => $value) 
       {
            echo "<tr><td>$name</td><td>$value</td></tr>";
       }
       echo "</table>";
    }       
}
```